# Getting an average of a field but grouping by data from another table using SQL JOIN

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the average rating of apps with the same ID.

For example the app with the AppID of 1 should only display one record displaying an average Rating of 3.333 and the other record should be AppID of 14 with an avg rating of 4.

```
SELECT reviews.Rating, reviews.AppID, apps.AppID, apps.image, apps.AppName, apps.Accepted 
FROM reviews 
JOIN apps 
WHERE reviews.AppID = apps.AppID
```

So far the results give a separate rating for each ID.

I tried

```
GROUP BY AppID
```

with

```
AVG(Rating)
```

but I just cant quite get it. 
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT AppID, AVG(Rating) AS AverageRating
FROM reviews 
GROUP BY AppID
```

If you need the fields from the apps table, you can try this:

```
SELECT r.AverageRating, a.AppID, a.image, a.AppName, a.Accepted 
FROM apps a 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT AppID, AVG(Rating) AS AverageRating
FROM reviews 
GROUP BY AppID) r
ON r.AppID = a.AppID
```

Comment: did not OP wrote that he already tried GROUP by AppId with AVG(Rating)?

Comment: The above t-sql statement will not duplicate rows for you.

Comment: thanks but it needs the join cause I need the data in the apps table but by getting the average of the rating in the review table.

Comment: Emma, try the second query in my post

Comment: when i use avg(rating) it just averages all of the ratings not for each app

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer already given is correct.  However, the OP was trying to get a bunch of columns.  Perhaps the only issue was the group by needed to be wider.  The OP did not comment on why the group by failed, whether it returned an unwanted result or if it didn't work. Using the OP's select target list, the group by would have to be pretty wide, like:

```
SELECT reviews.Rating, reviews.AppID, apps.AppID, apps.image, apps.AppName, apps.Accepted 
FROM reviews 
JOIN apps 
WHERE reviews.AppID = apps.AppID
group by reviews.AppID, apps.AppID, apps.image, apps.AppName, apps.Accepted
```

-g